# Can't use SSH public/private key pairs after moving home to NFS server

Tags: centos, ssh, arch-linux, nfs

I'm trying to understand why moving home directories on (2) different VMs screws up SSH public/private key authentication on one, but not the other. I am in the process of moving all of my local user accounts' home directory to an NFS server; the new home will be **/VM-home/username**. I copied the current home directories with **rsync -auv**, so the permissions are correct (0700 on $HOME/.ssh). After changing my home directory in **/etc/passwd**, I rebooted each system.

As you can see, the SSH connection works as expected on ArcoLinux, but fails on CentOS. I know that CentOS sees my new home, as logging on via Virt-Manager works; I've even deleted the old home just to make sure it wasn't being used. I would like to get this solved before continuing to reconfigure my other VMs.

**$ ssh -v qemu-arcolinux**

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to qemu-arcolinux [192.168.122.19] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to qemu-arcolinux:22 as 'summersd'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: XXXXXXXXXX
debug1: Host 'qemu-arcolinux' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA XXXXXXXXXX /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to qemu-arcolinux ([192.168.122.19]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /VM-home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /VM-home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Tue Jan 14 19:00:50 2020 from 192.168.122.1
```

**$ ssh -v qemu-centos**

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to qemu-centos [192.168.122.16] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to qemu-centos:22 as 'me'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: XXXXXXXXXX
debug1: Host 'qemu-centos' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,null>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA XXXXXXXXXX /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
me@qemu-centos: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: I had the same problem on CentOS, and I know for sure that it was because of SELinux, but unfortunately I don't remember exactly how I had fixed it ;-) It _may_ have been something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868601/10306503): `setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs 1`

Comment: This at least gives me something to go on.

Comment: @mosvy - it's definitely an issue with SELinux, but none of the fixes I've found, including yours, are working (broken on CentOS and Fedora).

Comment: What version of centos is that? (`cat /etc/centos-release`). What do you have in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`? Have you tried installing policycoreutils-python and running the `audit2why` command from the linked answer?

Comment: @mosvy - I'm running CentOS v8. I tried to run the command in the answer you linked, but I'm getting this: *ValueError: You must specify the -p option with the path to the policy file.*. For now I've disabled SELinux until I can get it to work.

Comment: I've just tried the `audit2why` and `setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs 1` commands on a vanilla rhel8 machine and they work as expected. I doubt that it's different in rhel from centos. You should run the `audit2why` with SELinux __enabled__; that error suggests that you have disabled it.

Comment: @mosvy - I tried to re-enable SELinux and the system crashed, booted into emergency mode. I'll give this another try when I have more time. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

After moving my home directory to a new drive I ran into the same issue. It was indeed related to selinux as setting it to permissive mode allowed me to connect over ssh. But when in enforcing mode, I couldnt connect. Long story short, you have to set a default selinux context for those folders.

This command will recursively update the selinux context for your home folder and should fix the issue.

```
restorecon -Rv /home
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I can't test this - switched to **VMware**, dumped SSH - hopefully someone else will benefit from this info.